# Origin of letter "X" for close icon

Tags: history, user-interface

Who exactly presented the idea that letter "X" should be used for closing/exiting a window or an application?

According to [Medium.com](https://medium.com/solve-for-x/x-to-close-417936dfc0dc),

> The first appearance of [x] in GUI design was likely the **Atari TOS**, possibly influenced by the Japanese **batsu** and **maru** conventions. Thanks to a last minute design change in **Windows 95**, and the mass adoption of Windows worldwide, [x] has become the standard symbol for ‘close’, a symbol that dominates web, app and software design today.

It is stating that letter "x" for closing/exiting a app originated around 1995 but according to my senior, letter "x" for exit was used first in 1980's in  **wordstar 4** on CP/M OS.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first GUI use of X for exit was Atari TOS in 1985.

[image]

The first PC keyboard shortcut use of X for exit may have been the North Star Horizon OS, which dates back to 1977.

[image]

In the early Wordstar versions, X was used for down-line and there was no mouse, obviously.

[image]

Comment: But I still don't get it, why they used X for close icon? They could have used any other character ...

Comment: @SilviuBurcea: Could it be because the X looks like a cross (and that the close icon is a cross, not an X)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I disagree. why do you think close icon is a cross? AFAIK,  as the letter 'x' in the word 'exit' demands a greater phonetic stress, it became an automatic choice for keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea X = eXit. Keyboard interfaces used X to exit, then when displays became more point and click the X became the button to indicate where to click.

Comment: @Liath but why they didn't choose E? Ok, it's awkward since X is also better looking, but I'm curious :)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea just a guess, maybe it was already registered for "Edit".

Comment: Actually, they used E for rename ... without R even being used ...

Comment: @SilviuBurcea R was used for Run.

Comment: @Mr_Green: There are usually (subtle typographic) differences between a close icon and an X in a GUI. But I can fully understand that the icon *resembles* an X because of the common use of X as a shortcut to exit the application.

Comment: looks more like Ctrl-X, Ctrl-E, etc. :)

Comment: As far as I can tell there was no X for closing windows on the Atari. The "close window" icon looks more arrows (representing a resizing of the window to zero size) like the "maximize" icon in the top right or the "resize" icon in the bottom right corner. That symbol also appeared in file selection dialogs where it represented "parent directory". The first example I know of something resembling an X for closing windows was in NeXTSTEP 0.8 from 1988.

Comment: @kolrabi what about Windows 95?

Comment: @Mr_Green Windows 95 was released later (in 1995). I think they might have just adopted it from NeXTSTEP.

Comment: @kolrabi ahh sorry..  I overlooked 1988 as 1998 :)

Comment: Digging a bit deeper, I found the AT&T Unix PC, released in 1985. Its GUI had windows with a button containing an "X" in the bottom left corner for closing them.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea "why not E" - because when you say 'exit' you *say* 'x-it'